# Find which Safari window is playing video?

Tags: macos, safari, video, safari-windows

Safari 9.0.1 launches and restores previously open windows. The app has the rude default behavior of automatically restarting any open videos.

With many open windows and tabs, how can I find the window playing the video?

In Chrome, I can use Window > Task Manager to view a list of processes. The busy one has the video. Double-clicking brings that window to the front. Anything similar in Safari?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Safari 9 (and probably later), a blue speaker icon appears in the URL bar of all windows whenever any window is playing audio. You can click on this to mute the current tab (if it's playing audio) or all other tabs (if the current one is playing audio).

This icon also has a hidden feature: If you click and hold on it, you will see a list of all the tabs that are currently playing sound. Click on one of those, and the corresponding window will be brought to the front. Then you can stop that particular video.

[image: screen shot of the "Tabs With Sound" menu]

Comment: This solved it for me.  Thank you so much, and shame on Apple for making this functionality practically undiscoverable.  Who would ever think to click and hold?

Answer (score 1):

in the latest version of Safari, the Tab(s) which are playing audio/video will show a small Speaker icon on the right-side of the Tab. you can click on the speaker to Mute the audio. the address bar also shows the speaker icon with the playing tab is selected, playing in the foreground.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question fully because you didn't answer how to tell which WINDOW contains the playing video.  If, like me, you have 20 Safari windows, it's impossible to tell which one is playing video without having to go through each tab in each window.  It's very annoying and something that I consider to be a glaring omission in Apple's flagship browser.